# Unable to bind the value based on the condition in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to bind the response object to html page based on the condition, if the value is 999999 then it must return null or nothing should be binded other than that the value must be binded but i'm unable to compare the number value of 'element.offersTransactionCap'.
The datatype of the 'element.offersTransactionCap' is number as well

```
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="jss203421"> {{element.offersTransactionCap==999999?'':element.offersTransactionCap}} </td>
```

Comment: it's looks like OK, try write only `{{element.offersTransactionCap}}` to see what Angular show :(

Comment: Thanks Eliseo, i mapped that response array into customized array and it was working fine.